# Vba + Match + IF

Tags: excel

I have the excel formula below and is not working the way I want, I maybe writing it wrongly.

```
=VLOOKUP(B$22,Scenarios.New!$A$1:$M$211,IF(MATCH(Output!$A35,Scenarios.New!$A$1:$M$1,0)=2,FALSE))
```

I Want to vlookup the B22 if the Output35 is equal 2.

[image]

[image]

So if the Action No is = 2 then Vlookup. Any ideas? Thanks!

[image]

Comment: MATCH returns the relative position of the match so unless `Action No.` is in B1 it will always return false or 0 and `0` cannot be the third criterion in a VLOOKUP.  What you want is and INDEX/MATCH where you match multiple columns.  Google that and you should get many examples.

Answer (score 0):

You are defining it the other way around... You should check if the condition is true first, then if it's true... "Vlookup(....)", if not, whatever you want. Try it, I think it should do what you want.

=IF(MATCH(Output!$A35,Scenarios.New!$A$1:$M$1,0)=2,FALSE), VLOOKUP(B$22,Scenarios.New!$A$1:$M$211)

Comment: yeah deffinitelly there are too few arguments... but the definition of the function is a bit ambiguous... Is there any reason why you are using match?

Why don't you try...

=IF(B35=2,VLOOKUP(B$22,Scenarios.New!$A$1:$M$211, COLUMNARGUMENT, FALSE)

Comment: Check my new image, the problem i am facing is that sometimes i have more than one action, so when I v look up the number 4, for example, will ignore the 2nd 4 and i will miss some piece of information

Comment: I couldn't understand what was your purpose very clearly, but I agree with Scott's answer, INDEX / MATCH  will do what you want to do. Take care with the order of the data, depending on which kind of match you want to get you should order it ascendin / descending way.